# Adding a column with random values to end of CSV

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I have a CSV with a list of users, and would like to add a column with a one-time-use randomly generated password, unique to each user.

My script works... but then it just keeps going indefinitely adding rows.   If I move the code to set the variable out of the loop, it works just fine, but then every user gets the same password.

How do I get this to terminate on the last row?

```
#!/bin/bash
#add column to csv
ORIG_FILE="new-users2.csv"
NEW_FILE="Output.csv"
{ echo `head -1 $ORIG_FILE`",One Time Password" ; tail -n +2 $ORIG_FILE | \
  while read x ; OneTimePass=$(openssl rand -base64 14 | head -c 6) ; do echo "$x,$OneTimePass" ; done ; } > $NEW_FILE
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please edit your post to include an (anonymized) example of the CSV file before the operation, with the corresponding desired result of the operation. Also, consider including the undesired result that your code produces at the moment.

Comment: Always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process.

Answer (score 6):

You have the syntax of your `while...do...done` loop wrong. You are running this:

```
while read x ; OneTimePass=$(openssl rand -base64 14 | head -c 6) ; do ...
```

The `while` keyword's expected format is explained in `help while`:

```
$ help while
while: while COMMANDS; do COMMANDS; done
    Execute commands as long as a test succeeds.
    
    Expand and execute COMMANDS as long as the final command in the
    `while' COMMANDS has an exit status of zero.
    
    Exit Status:
    Returns the status of the last command executed.
```

Here, you are giving it two commands: `read x ;` and `OneTimePass=$(openssl rand -base64 14 | head -c 6)`, and the second command always works, it doesn't have any ending since you can always re-run the `openssl` command. This is why the `while` loop never exits and you just keep writing more and more lines. What you're after is this:

```
while read x; do
    something
done
```

Here's a working version of your script with some other improvements such as proper quoting and avoiding CAPS for your variable names:

```
#!/bin/bash

#add column to csv
orig_file="new-users2.csv"
new_file="Output.csv"

printf "%s,%s\n" "$(head -1 "$orig_file")" "One Time Password" > "$new_file"
tail -n +2 "$orig_file" |
  while read -r x; do
    OneTimePass="$(openssl rand -base64 14 | head -c 6)"
    printf '%s,%s\n' "$x" "$OneTimePass"
  done >> "$new_file"
```

Personally, I would avoid hardcoding the file names since that makes the script harder to use and less versatile. I would instead take the input file name as an argument, and then print to standard output so you can choose whatever output file you want:

```
#!/bin/bash

#add column to csv
orig_file=$1

printf "%s,%s\n" "$(head -1 "$orig_file")" "One Time Password"
tail -n +2 "$orig_file" |
  while read -r x; do
    OneTimePass="$(openssl rand -base64 14 | head -c 6)"
    printf '%s,%s\n' "$x" "$OneTimePass"
  done
```

You can then run it like this:

```
foo.sh new-users2.csv > Output.csv
```

I tested with this input file:

```
$ cat new-users2.csv 
name,age
Bob,45
Alice,36
```

Which results in:

```
$ foo.sh new-users2.csv 
name,age,One Time Password
Bob,45,BTkLQW
Alice,36,CzQa4U
```

Comment: You are awesome.   Thank you so much!  This was helpful on a number of levels.

Comment: You're very welcome @MrS! If this or any other answer here solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](//unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the checkmark on the left. That is the best way to express your thanks on the Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 5):

Using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), and cheekily borrowing [@terdon's example file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/662513/65304)

```
$ mlr --csv put -S '
    $["One Time Password"] = substr(system("openssl rand -base64 5"),0,5)
' new-users2.csv 
name,age,One Time Password
Bob,45,kIrlrl
Alice,36,h1OBp3
```

(I changed the `openssl rand` parameter from 14 to 5 bytes since you should need no more than 36 bits to generate six base64 characters. Change it back if it is important for some reason.)

You can do a similar thing with awk's `system()` function but handling of the CSV structure and headers is messier. Perhaps neater with awk would be to use `getline` ex.:

```
$ awk -F, '
    BEGIN {OFS=FS; cmd = "openssl rand -base64 5"} 
    NR==1 {$(NF+1) = "One Time Password"} 
    NR >1 {cmd | getline var; close(cmd); $(NF+1) = substr(var,1,6)} 
    1
' new-users2.csv
name,age,One Time Password
Bob,45,CovLkz
Alice,36,PgLbD4
```

Unlike the Miller version, this will only work for "simple" CSV (it won't handle embedded "," characters within fields for example).

Comment: @rowboat thanks can't believe I didn't spot that - should be better now I think?